# ERROR 2100 HDD0 boot error disk not found windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, ssd, hardware-failure

today I started my ThinkPad T400 to do some changes in switchable graphics driver. During installation of driver of internal graphic card bluescreen error occured (SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED). I rebooted my laptop and common problem occured when I do something wrong with graphic card drivers. I usually restore system to last restorepoint and than it work perfectly again. But today it wasn't.
I restored system, then restarted laptop and it booted but blank screen was shown with no cursor or anything. So I many times tried to restard and also restore to older restore point but I wasn't able to restore because it shows that I must disable disk protection or something like that. And suddenly I wasn't able to start boot of system. It crashed with error 2100 HDD0 main disk drive initialization error (2) or something like that. When I entered bios it cannot recognise my system disk SSD OCZ 60GB.

Does anybody know what can be problem? Can it be solved? I searched through net but noone bring a solution. Some users said that they replaced ssd with new and same error occured in few days. I'm really depressed. I have that disk just one year and it worked perfectly everytime. And also I have all my work from school there also with my past exercises and present work also bachelor thesis etc. I use it almost everyday as IT student. Please help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS suddenly can't see your drive, and you've changed nothing, then it sounds like your SSD died to me.

Try a known-good replacement drive and see if that works, and try the suspect SSD in another computer.

If the SSD doesn't work in the other computer (and a known-good drive works in yours) then replace the SSD.

If the SSD can't be recognized by any computer's BIOS, then the odds of getting your data off it are basically none (at least not without [professional help](http://www.cbldatarecovery.ca/)), so you should restore your need data from your last backup (assuming you made one).

Comment: I need to know if it is just broken SSD or if something break it. In some threads I read that they replaced broken SSD with new one and after few days this new was broken too. Don't really want to happen this to me. is there any way to find out wheater my MOBO is broken or what else could made this problem to me?

Comment: @Gondil Not without swapping parts. What your afraid of is just one of those things when fixing computers.  You replace what you believe is faulty, and continue to do so as other faults are discovered. PS: the odds are good that your MB did not break your SSD, as that (practically) never happens.

Comment: I started my laptop with USB ubuntu. It can be good start as I think, don't you think so? Is it possible to run system on laptop this way in case that some important hardware as MOBO is broken? Is this "telling" me that just SSD is out of its life? My friend from which I bought that SSD told me that it can be about 4-5 year old disk.. My laptop too anyway. Maybe I'm quite old school when I want from todays electronics to work for example 10 years :D